# Addition of Array with integer value gives '0' always

Tags: c++, arrays

I am developing a program in which I have to read a text file and store the integer values in an array from the text file. I have searched for how to do and found this [method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47191810/read-from-a-text-file-and-storing-to-an-array-c). But the result is not as expected.

For instance, say, I have integer values in a text file called 'integers.txt' such as 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10. I am reading those values and add it one by one with the new array called 'myarray'. But after performing an addition, using while loop, I have got only zero as output in 'myarray'

Here is my code:

```
int main(int argc, char **argv) 
{
  int myArray[2048]={0};
  int value;
  int i = 0;
  while(file >> value && i<sizeof(myArray))
 { 
   myArray[i] += value;
   i++;
   std::cout<<myArray[i]<<std::endl;
   std::cout<<value<<std::endl;
 }  

 std::cout<<i<<std::endl;

 std::cout<< sizeof(myArray)<<std::endl;
 return 0;
}
```

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Edit your question to include a [mcve].

Comment: Did `std::cout<< sizeof(myArray)<<std::endl;` *really* print the number you expected?

Comment: @molbdnilo, No, I just need to show the size of the array

Comment: @Dhans I'll rephrase my question: did you notice that `sizeof(myArray)` is *not* the number of elements in the array?

Comment: @molbdnilo, Yes. It's the size of a number of total integers.

Comment: @Dhans Did you also consider that `sizeof(myArray)` - being the size of 2048 `int`s, which isn't 2048 - is not a good limit for the loop?

Comment: @molbdnilo, pardon. I couldn't get you!

Comment: This doesn't address the question, but do you really need the extra stuff that `std::endl` does? `'\n'` ends a line.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are incrementing i before printing the value and initially all array elements are initialised to 0.

So when we reach at the last integer of file, it stores it and increments i to a value which is out-of-bounds. Increment i after the print statements

Answer (score 2):

`i` is incremented too early. Do it after the printing.

```
while(file >> value && i<sizeof(myArray))
{ 
   myArray[i] += value;
   std::cout<<myArray[i]<<std::endl;
   std::cout<<value<<std::endl;

   i++; // ~~~~ Do it after the printing.
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe the output differs from what you expect because you try to add value to a slot of array which is not set. Try changing:

```
myArray[i] += value;
```

To:

```
myArray[i] = value;
```

Comment: That is irrelevant, since the array is zero-initialized.

Answer (score 0):

```
   myArray[i] += value;
   i++;
   std::cout<<myArray[i]<<std::endl;
```

You assign a value to `myArray[i]`, then you increment `i` before using it to print `myArray[i]`, so you end up printing the next value in `myArray` rather than the one you just modified.

Swapping the two last lines takes care of that:

```
   myArray[i] += value;
   std::cout<<myArray[i]<<std::endl;
   i++;
```

---

Also note that if your file contains more than `2048` numbers, you will access memory outside `myarray` and your program is likely to crash.  So instead of this:

```
while(file >> value && i<sizeof(myArray))
```

do something like this:

```
while(file >> value && i < sizeof(myArray) / sizeof(myArray[0]))
```